# "Percentage of people who ... but ..." sentences

Tags: grammar

"Suppose that the percentage of people who were not tested but had the coronavirus is 1/4 that of those who were tested and had the coronavirus"

What is the correct way to interpret the subject of this sentence?

A) The percentage of (people) who (were not tested but had the coronavirus)

or

B) The percentage of (people who were not tested) but (had the coronavirus)

I believe B) is incorrect because it doesn't make sense to take the percentage of people BUT [insert verb]. You can only take the percentage of people WHO [insert verb].

My math teacher doesn't care much about grammar though...

EDIT: can someone tell me why I'm being downvoted?

Comment: What would be the actual difference in meaning between the two interpretations?

Comment: The context of the sentence should make it clear. There may even be a table or chart that shows the actual numbers.

Comment: A) is (number of people who were not tested but had the coronavirus) divided by (number of people).
B) is (number of people who were not tested but had the coronavirus) divided by (number people who were not tested)